# JSP for loop with database results

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, drop-down-menu

Im using JSP for an application for college. Corresponding with the JSP there is a connection to a database which i must retrieve the information and display it in a drop down list so the user can select one option to proceed with a registration form. I am able to connect to the DB no problem and output the information in the drop down but its only getting the very first row that was entered into the database.

```
String[] course_codes = dbclass.SelectRow("SELECT DISTINCT Course_code FROM Stream ;");
                %><form action="successtwo.jsp">
                    <label>Select Course code</label> 
                    <select name="stream">
                         <%for(String course_code: course_codes){
                         out.println("<option value="+course_code+">"+course_code+"</option>");
}%>
                   </select><br>
```

So I have done something like this but I also have done this.

```
String[] course_codes = dbclass.SelectRow("SELECT DISTINCT Course_code FROM Stream ;");
                %><form action="successtwo.jsp">
                    <label>Select Course code</label> 
                    <select name="stream">
                         <%for(String course_code: course_codes){%>

                       <option value="<%=course_code%>"><%=course_code%></option> 

                           <%}%>
                   </select><br>
```

In the database there is more than one Course_code and also the same Course_code can appear hence why i use distinct. Here is the dbClass.java where the SelectRow method is.

```
 public String[] SelectRow(String SQLquery)
{
    String Result[];
    // Send an SQL query to a database and return the *single column* result in an array of strings
    try {// Make connection to database
        statementObject = connectionObject.createStatement();

        ResultSet statementResult = statementObject.executeQuery(SQLquery); //Should connection be left open?

        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = statementResult.getMetaData();
        int nrOfColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();

        Result = new String[nrOfColumns];

        statementResult.next();

        int currentCounter = 0;

        while (currentCounter<nrOfColumns) // While there are rows to process
        {
            // Get the first cell in the current row
            Result[currentCounter] = statementResult.getString(currentCounter+1);
            currentCounter++;

        }
        // Close the link to the database when finished

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Select problems with SQL " + SQLquery);
        System.err.println("Select problem is " + e.getMessage());
        Result = new String[0]; //Need to setup result array to avoid initialisation error
        writeLogSQL(SQLquery + " caused error " + e.getMessage());
        }
    writeLogSQL(SQLquery + "worked ");
    return Result;
} // End SelectRow
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
public String[] SelectColumn(String SQLquery)
{
    String Result[];
    // Send an SQL query to a database and return the *single column* result in an array of strings
    try {// Make connection to database
        statementObject = connectionObject.createStatement(); //Should connection be left open?

        ResultSet statementResult = statementObject.executeQuery(SQLquery);

        // Start solution from http://www.coderanch.com/t/303346/JDBC/java/find-number-rows-resultset
        int rowcount = 0;
        if (statementResult.last()) {
            rowcount = statementResult.getRow();
            statementResult.beforeFirst(); // not rs.first() because the rs.next() below will move on, missing the first element
            }
        // End solution from http://www.coderanch.com/t/303346/JDBC/java/find-number-rows-resultset

        Result = new String[rowcount];

        int currentCounter = 0;

        while (statementResult.next()) // While there are rows to process
        {
            // Get the first cell in the current row
            Result[currentCounter] = statementResult.getString(1);
            currentCounter++;

        }
        // Close the link to the database when finished
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Select problems with SQL " + SQLquery);
        System.err.println("Select problem is " + e.getMessage());
        Result = new String[0]; //Need to setup result array to avoid initialisation error
        writeLogSQL(SQLquery + " caused error " + e.getMessage());
        }
    writeLogSQL(SQLquery + "worked ");
    return Result;
} // End Select
```

This worked...

Answer (score 0):

Use resultSet.next() to move resultSet to the next Row.

To Loop through the resultSet you could use something like this

```
while (rs.next()) {
    Result[currentCounter] = statementResult.getString("columnName");
}
```

Here is a sample http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html

Comment: Your answered worked for a different part but i found a reason why it wouldnt work. I was getting the row when i wanted the column. here is the column code. Thanks nevertheless :-)